# Erro ao executar trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, pdo, active-record

Boa tarde guerreiros, estou tendo um problema para implementar uma trigger no mysql. Ocorre que eu criei uma tabela chamada auditoria com a mesma estrutura da tabela principal de atendimentos, essa tabela auditoria registra todos os eventos, ações que são feitas na tabela atendimento.
Esta funcionando tudo certinho, porem surgiu uma nova necessidade, quando o atendimento é finalizado o campo state=1 deve ficar igual state=2, para isso eu modifiquei a trigger ja existente para ficar da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `nomebanco`.`tabela_atendimento_triggernome` AFTER UPDATE ON `tabela_atendimento` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    IF NEW.finalizar_atendimento = '1' THEN
        UPDATE tabela_atendimento SET state = '2' WHERE id = NEW.id;

    ELSE

        INSERT INTO tabela_atendimento_auditoria
        (
        id,
        asset_id,
        ordering,
        state,
        tem_cadastro,
        criarcadastro,
        objetivo,
        corretor_nome,
        corretor_email,
        empreendimento,
        empreendimento_unidade,
        empreendimento_torre,
        data_hora_visita,
        observacoes,
        valorproposta,
        situacao_proposta,
        contra_proposta,
        finalizar_atendimento,
        finalizar_motivo,
        outro_empreendimento,
        responsavel
        )
        VALUES
        (
        NEW.id,
        NEW.asset_id,
        NEW.ordering,
        NEW.state,
        NEW.tem_cadastro,
        NEW.criarcadastro,
        NEW.objetivo,
        NEW.corretor_nome,
        NEW.corretor_email,
        NEW.empreendimento,
        NEW.empreendimento_unidade,
        NEW.empreendimento_torre,
        NEW.data_hora_visita,
        NEW.observacoes,
        NEW.valorproposta,
        NEW.situacao_proposta,
        NEW.contra_proposta,
        NEW.finalizar_atendimento,
        NEW.finalizar_motivo,
        NEW.outro_empreendimento,
        NEW.responsavel
        );

    END IF;
END
```

**antes de colocar o IF funcionava perfeitamente, porem agora eu tenho o retorno de um erro no PHP com o seguinte conteudo:**

O salvamento falhou por conta do seguinte erro:

> Can't update table '#_atendimento' in stored function/trigger because
>   it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
>   function/trigger. SQL=UPDATE #_atendimento SET
>   ordering='2',state='1',tem_cadastro='1',criarcadastro='0',objetivo='2',corretor_nome='19',corretor_email='19',empreendimento='2',empreendimento_unidade='3',empreendimento_torre='1',data_hora_visita='2016-01-01
>   00:00:01',observacoes='bla
>   bla',valorproposta='120.000,00',situacao_proposta='2',contra_proposta='110.000,00',finalizar_atendimento='1',finalizar_motivo='1',outro_empreendimento='',responsavel='718',data_hora_registro='2016-07-29
>   14:04:39' WHERE id='2'

**eu entendo que não posso executar duas ações no mesmo momento por conta da tabela, e eu não posso mexer no CRUD do PHP por restrições, então minha saída nesse momento foi trabalhar com as triggers.**

Answer (score 0):

Acontece que você definiu uma trigger para a tabela **`tabela_atendimento`** onde a trigger é disparada no evento UPDATE, correto!?

Mas na sua trigger você está tentando fazer um update na mesma tabela, você está  tentando chamar a trigger recursivamente, entende!?

```
...
IF NEW.finalizar_atendimento = '1' THEN
   UPDATE tabela_atendimento SET state = '2' WHERE id = NEW.id;
ELSE
...
```

Não seria sua idéia fazer um UPDATE na tabela **`tabela_atendimento_auditoria`**?

**UPDATE**

Com base [neste tópico do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17823477/1997073) e na documentação sugerida no mesmo tópico. Entendo que, se você fizer a atualização do campo STATE em uma trigger disparada no evento BEFORE UPDATE, talvez de certo.

IF NEW.finalizar_atendimento = '1' THEN
   SET NEW.STATE = 2;

Isso pelo fato que falei antes, você não pode usar uma trigger para atualizar a mesma tabela que está sendo chamada no evento da query. Mas nesse caso você estaria alterando o valor da linha já selecionada antes de fazer o UPDATE.

Comment: Não, a ideia é exatamente atualizar a tabela atendimento mesmo, porque quando mudar o state para 2 significa que esse atendimento foi finalizado e ele vai ficar oculto na lista de atendimentos dos operadores

Comment: Fiz um update na resposta, veja se resolve. Lembre-se de alterar a trigger do AFTER UPDATE.